# Gulp Failure (Mean.io, npm) Due to CSSLint

Tags: npm, gulp, mean-stack, mean.io, csslint

I am trying to get a Mean.io project running. I made some simple HTML changes and some simple controller changes just to learn how the project was set up. It was early enough in learning how to get the project set up that I didn't check anything into source control and after messing around for a bit, I'd delete the project and start over (I've done this a few times).

Every time I initialized the project, I followed the Mean.io documentation and did:

```
mean init projectName
cd projectName && npm install
gulp
```

This worked MULTIPLE times. Then all of a sudden, it STOPPED working and gulp won't start everything up anymore. No versions have changed that I'm aware of. I keep getting this output as a result of running gulp:

> $ gulp (node:9800) fs: re-evaluating native module
>   sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module,
>   please update it to a more recent version. Invoking gulp - development
>   [18:11:02] Using gulpfile
>   C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\gulpfile.js [18:11:02]
>   Starting 'clean'... [18:11:02] Finished 'clean' after 5.78 ms
>   [18:11:02] Starting 'default'... [18:11:02] Starting
>   'webpack:build-dev'... [18:11:02] Starting 'clean'... [18:11:02]
>   Starting 'less'... [18:11:02] Starting 'sass'... [18:11:02] Starting
>   'csslint'... [18:11:02] 'csslint' errored after 55 ms [18:11:02]
>   TypeError: plugins.csslint.reporter is not a function   at
>   Gulp.
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\gulp\development.js:52:27)
>   at module.exports
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator.start
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:134:8)
>   at Gulp.
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\gulpfile.js:16:8)   at
>   module.exports
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
>   at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
>   at
>   C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:279:18
>   at finish
>   (C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
>   at
>   C:\workspace\learning\mean\tour\toursey\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:43:4
>
> [18:11:02] Finished 'clean' after 255 ms [18:11:02] Finished 'less'
>   after 722 ms [18:11:02] Finished 'sass' after 542 ms [18:11:08]
>   [webpack:build-dev] Hash: d3d41231974f858a22db Version: webpack 1.13.2
>   Time: 6019ms
>        Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
>       app.js  2.87 MB       0  [emitted]  main app.js.map  3.38 MB       0  [emitted]  main chunk    {0} app.js, app.js.map (main) 2.79 MB
>   [rendered]
>       [0] ./app.js 1.64 kB {0} [built]
>       [1] ./bower_components/angular/angular-csp.css 937 bytes {0} [built]
>       [2] ./~/css-loader!./bower_components/angular/angular-csp.css 569 bytes {0} [built]
>       [3] ./~/css-loader/lib/css-base.js 1.51 kB {0} [built]
>       [4] ./~/style-loader/addStyles.js 7.15 kB {0} [built]
>       [5] ./~/angular-ui-select/select.min.css 870 bytes {0} [built]
>       [6] ./~/css-loader!./~/angular-ui-select/select.min.css 4.34 kB {0} [built]
>       [7] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css 967 bytes {0} [built]
>       [8] ./~/css-loader!./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>   122 kB {0} [built]
>       [9] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
>   26.9 kB {0} [built]    [10] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>   24.1 kB {0} [built]    [11] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
>   31.3 kB {0} [built]    [12] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
>   60.6 kB {0} [built]    [13] ./bower_components/bootstrap/dist/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
>   145 kB {0} [built]    [14] ./~/jquery/dist/jquery.js 264 kB {0}
>   [built]    [15] ./bower_components/angular/index.js 50 bytes {0}
>   [built]    [16] ./bower_components/angular/angular.js 1.22 MB {0}
>   [built]    [17] ./~/angular-ui-select/select.js 76.4 kB {0} [built]
>   [18] ./bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js 112 kB {0}
>   [built]    [19] ./bower_components/angular-cookies/index.js 62 bytes
>   {0} [built]    [20]
>   ./bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js 10.1 kB {0}
>   [built]    [21] ./bower_components/angular-resource/index.js 64 bytes
>   {0} [built]    [22]
>   ./bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js 36.1 kB {0}
>   [built]    [23] ./bower_components/angular-sanitize/index.js 64 bytes
>   {0} [built]    [24]
>   ./bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js 27.6 kB {0}
>   [built]    [25] ./~/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js 172
>   kB {0} [built]    [26] ./~/angular-jwt/index.js 67 bytes {0} [built]
>   [27] ./~/angular-jwt/dist/angular-jwt.js 12.5 kB {0} [built]    [28]
>   ./bower_components/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js 274 kB {0}
>   [built]    [29] ./packages /public/(?!tests|assets|views)(.*).js$
>   436 bytes {0} [built]    [30]
>   ./packages/custom/toursey/public/controllers/header.js 1.3 kB {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [31]
>   ./packages/custom/toursey/public/controllers/index.js 2.11 kB {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [32]
>   ./packages/custom/toursey/public/controllers/starter.js 363 bytes {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [33] ./packages/custom/toursey/public/index.js
>   129 bytes {0} [optional] [built]    [34]
>   ./packages/custom/toursey/public/assets/css/common.css 970 bytes {0}
>   [built]    [35]
>   ./~/css-loader!./packages/custom/toursey/public/assets/css/common.css
>   1.12 kB {0} [built]    [36] ./packages/custom/toursey/public/assets/css/loginForms.css 982 bytes
>   {0} [built]    [37]
>   ./~/css-loader!./packages/custom/toursey/public/assets/css/loginForms.css
>   12.8 kB {0} [built]    [38] ./packages/custom/toursey/public/assets/css/starter.css 973 bytes {0}
>   [built]    [39]
>   ./~/css-loader!./packages/custom/toursey/public/assets/css/starter.css
>   5.59 kB {0} [built]    [40] ./packages/custom/toursey/public/routes/system.js 522 bytes {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [41]
>   ./packages/custom/toursey/public/routes/users.js 1.22 kB {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [42] ./node_modules
>   /meanio-(.*)/public/(?!tests|assets|views)(.*).js$ 1.39 kB {0}
>   [built]    [43] ./~/meanio-admin/public/controllers/admin.js 1.26 kB
>   {0} [optional] [built]    [44]
>   ./~/meanio-admin/public/controllers/example.js 565 bytes {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [45]
>   ./~/meanio-admin/public/controllers/modules.js 431 bytes {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [46]
>   ./~/meanio-admin/public/controllers/settings.js 3.16 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [47] ./~/meanio-admin/public/controllers/themes.js 1.68 kB
>   {0} [optional] [built]    [48]
>   ./~/meanio-admin/public/controllers/users.js 3.24 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [49] ./~/meanio-admin/public/directives/editable.js 3.42 kB
>   {0} [optional] [built]    [50] ./~/meanio-admin/public/index.js 124
>   bytes {0} [optional] [built]    [51]
>   ./~/meanio-admin/public/assets/css/admin.css 891 bytes {0} [built]
>   [52] ./~/css-loader!./~/meanio-admin/public/assets/css/admin.css 3.77
>   kB {0} [built]    [53] ./~/zeroclipboard/dist/ZeroClipboard.js 85.6 kB
>   {0} [built]    [54] ./~/ng-clip/dest/ng-clip.min.js 1.18 kB {0}
>   [built]    [55] ./~/meanio-admin/public/routes/admin.js 1.25 kB {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [56]
>   ./~/meanio-admin/public/services/module-settings.js 1.03 kB {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [57] ./~/meanio-admin/public/services/modules.js
>   353 bytes {0} [optional] [built]    [58]
>   ./~/meanio-admin/public/services/settings.js 1.04 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [59] ./~/meanio-admin/public/services/users.js 326 bytes
>   {0} [optional] [built]    [60]
>   ./~/meanio-circles/public/controllers/circles.js 763 bytes {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [61] ./~/meanio-circles/public/index.js 53 bytes
>   {0} [optional] [built]    [62]
>   ./~/meanio-circles/public/assets/css/circles.css 897 bytes {0} [built]
>   [63] ./~/css-loader!./~/meanio-circles/public/assets/css/circles.css
>   570 bytes {0} [built]    [64]
>   ./~/meanio-circles/public/routes/circles.js 1.65 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [65] ./~/meanio-circles/public/services/circles.js 515
>   bytes {0} [optional] [built]    [66]
>   ./~/meanio-system/public/routes/system.js 1.27 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [67] ./~/meanio-system/public/services/config.js 577 bytes
>   {0} [optional] [built]    [68]
>   ./~/meanio-system/public/services/global.js 3.94 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [69] ./~/meanio-system/public/services/interceptor.js 913
>   bytes {0} [optional] [built]    [70]
>   ./~/meanio-system/public/services/menus.js 228 bytes {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [71] ./~/meanio-system/public/system.js 537 bytes {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [72]
>   ./~/meanio-users/public/controllers/meanUser.js 4.18 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built]    [73] ./~/meanio-users/public/index.js 40 bytes {0}
>   [optional] [built]    [74] ./~/meanio-users/public/routes/auth.js 359
>   bytes {0} [optional] [built]    [75]
>   ./~/meanio-users/public/services/meanUser.js 6.79 kB {0} [optional]
>   [built] [18:11:08] Finished 'webpack:build-dev' after 6.03 s

Any ideas on how to resolve this? I'm not sure if something is being cached somewhere or something? The only semi-useful thing I saw in the output was the CSSLint issue, but I'm not sure that that wasn't already happening before, and if it's the culprit, I have not been able to find a way to resolve it anywhere.

**UPDATE**
I removed the references to CSSLint in the gulp/development.js file and it works again, so it definitely appears that the CSSLint package is causing this. I'm pretty new to npm, how is it possible that this would work and all of a sudden quit working when no dependency versions have been updated?

Comment: I have created an issue here:https://github.com/linnovate/mean/issues/1634 You can keep a track of changes there.